# Как отследить, чтобы логарифм из отрицательного числа не вычислялся

Tags: c#, математика

Нужно написать программу решающую следующий пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код печатает NaN - Not a Number.
Я понимаю что дело в том, что  Log не может быть отрицательным. Но тогда каким образом решить задачу?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double y = Math.Log(4 - Math.Pow(x, 2));       
        Console.WriteLine(y);

    }    
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120798/discussion-on-question-by-valery-semenkin-c-----).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если программа выдает ошибку, что логарифм не может быть меньше нуля, это значит, что вы пытаетесь найти логарифм меньше нуля. В данном случае это возможно при **x > 2 или x < -2**

```
4 - x^2 < 0
-x^2 < -4   |*(-1)
x^2 > 4
x > 2 или x < -2
```

Значит нужно проверять: если модель x больше 2, то выводим сообщение о неправильном вводе, иначе считаем логарифм. Проверка - это ветвление, условный оператор if. Можно прочитать

- Здесь https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.5.php
- Здесь https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else

Код, таким образом, будет следующий:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        // Ввод x
        double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        // Если x соответствует условиям, т.е. |x| <= 2
        if (Math.Abs(x) < 2) {
            double y = Math.Log(4 - Math.Pow(x, 2));       
            Console.WriteLine(y);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка ввода. При введенных значениях требуется вычисление логарифма отрицательного числа");
    }    
}
```

Сообщение может быть какое захотите. Можете выбрасывать исключение, показывать картинку - это уже другая тема.

Comment: Помимо `Math.Pow(x, 2)` *можно* писать `x*x`

Comment: @EzikBro Вы правы, исправил:)

Comment: спасибо большое вам за помощь, такие люди как вы мотивируют меня учить язык:)

Answer (score 1):

Изменённый вариант

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if (x > -2 && x < 2)
{
    double y = Math.Log(4 - Math.Pow(x, 2));
    Console.WriteLine(y);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("X не входит в промежуток");
}
```

Comment: А зачем этот ответ? Я же уже дал вам ответ, и вы его приняли. В таком случае писать свой ответ не нужно :)

Comment: Он ещё тут до вашего ответа. Мне сначала другие люди помогали разобраться в теме. Просто ваш ответ более информативен и несёт в себе познавательную информацию(оставленные ссылки) Что полезно для людей с подобной ошибкой. Этот ответ я удалять не буду. Он работает, я не хочу чтоб труд людей которые мне помогали пропал, не красивый поступок.

Comment: В комментариях? Понятно, там просто в чат перенесли, я вообще не увидел комментарии :)